# How to know if an image is too dark that it needs flash using OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, android-camera

I'm working in an Android project using OpenCV and I'm using a surface to implement my own camera, because I want to provide the user with feedback about the picture they are taking to help them improve the quality of it. What I'm trying to do is to detect how dark the image they are about to take and suggest them to use the flash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: histograms are a very nice tool to judge image brightness and contrast. read something about them and how to interpret them. other than that there should be plenty of resources online. just google auto exposure algorithm e.g. you will find a lot of papers on what is going on in digital cameras. I'm sure there will be something useful about flash as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you have control over parameters of the camera*, consider making ajustments on them before using the flash. If you want a *x2* factor on global exposure, you can either:

- multiply ***exposure time*** by *2*
- divide aperture value (or ***f-number***) by *sqrt(2)*
- multiply ***gain*** by *2* (this will add some noise)

Now to answer the question, if you already know how to access pixels in your image with `OpenCV`, I first recommend you convert it to grayscale using `cvtColor`, then you can compute (for each image) the sum of pixel intensities (`cv::sum`) and define a threshold under which the image is "too dark".

Exemple of pseudo code (this should be refined according to your needs/application):

```
while sum(pixels) < threshold
   it_nb=0
   exp_time += 0.1 (second)
   if it_nb>fixed_limit or if (exp_time/gain cannot be increased anymore)
      print 'use flash'      
      break
```

Comment: please note that increasing the exposure time will also increase the noise.
I fixed an error in your answer. f-number has to be decreased in order to get more light!